# Can I use a custom word list for my wallet recovery phrase?

Tags: wallet, ada, recovery

Is it possible to use a custom list of words to generate my Cardano wallet recovery phrase?

The reason I think this would be useful is, that one could use words from other languages.

As far as I know the recovery phrase has a checksum (the last word), so it's not possible to just replace some words with random other words in an existing recovery phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CIP3: Wallet key generation](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0003/CIP-0003.md), Cardano is using seed words from [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md), therefore you can use words included in BIP39 only.

Answer (score 1):

As an architect/developer of your own crypto-wallet for personal use, you can declare your own list of 2048 words (although it's highly undesirable). However, if we talk about it in the sense of already existing products, such as Daedalus or Yoroi, it's impossible, because BIP39 wordlist is deeply integrated there.